# Is $\measuredangle ABF=\measuredangle DAE$ in a quadrilateral?

Tags: geometry

[image]

Is $\measuredangle ABF=\measuredangle DAE$ in quadrilateral $ABCD$?

I cannot find a way to answer this question. All I know is that $ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. I mused that $\measuredangle BAF=\measuredangle DAE$, but I am not sure if that is correct. Can someone help me please? If  $\measuredangle ABF=\measuredangle DAE$, **HOW?**

Comment: Perhaps all the extra information is clouding the issue. Look at the fact that angles $A$, $E$, and $F$ are all right angles. By the way, there must be a typo, as $\angle AEF = 180º$.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typo, but I can't get through to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Put $\;\angle DAE=\alpha\;$ , then

$$\begin{align}&\angle BAF=90^\circ-\alpha\;,\;\;\text{since we're given}\;\;\angle BAD=90^\circ\implies\\{}\\&\implies\angle ABF=\alpha\end{align}$$